# Snakemake wildcards from python wrapper not found

Tags: python, snakemake

I am new to using snakemake and I am having difficulty. I have written a python wrapper file to run make snakefile. The wrapper takes a samples.txt with taxon, read1, read2, adapters, and assembly (Y/N). If assembly is needed, the snakefile with assembly is run, if N, a snakefile without assembly is run. It seems like the correct snakefile is being run, but the information for the wildcards isn't being transferred from the wrapper to the snakefile.

samples.txt

```
Solatube DRR350770_1.fastq.gz DRR350770_2.fastq.gz all.fa Y
```

run_pipeline.py

```
import argparse
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run Snakemake pipeline with Trinity assemble or not")
parser.add_argument("samples", help="path to samples.txt")
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.samples) as f:
    for line in f:
        taxon, read1, read2, adapters, assembly = [x.strip() for x in line.split()]
        if assembly == "Y":
            os.system(f"snakemake -s SNPwAssembly.smk --cores 16 --config taxon={taxon} read1={read1} read2={read2} adapters={adapters}")
        elif assembly == "N":
            os.system(f"snakemake -s SNPwoAssembly≈.smk --cores 16 --config taxon={taxon} read1={read1} read2={read2} adapters={adapters}")
        else:
            print(f"Invalid value for assembly in line: {line}")
```

SNPwAssembly.smk begins:

```
import os

# define rules                                                                                                                                                                                  
rule all:                                                                                                                                                                                               
    input: expand("{taxon}.snpden", taxon = taxon)                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
rule trinity_assembly:                                                                                                                                                                                  

input:                                                                                                                                                                                              
    read1 = "{taxon}/{read1}",                                                                                                                                                                      
    read2 = "{taxon}/{read2}",                                                                                                                                                                      
    adapters = "{adapters}"                                                                                                                                                                         
output:                                                                                                                                                                                             
    "{taxon}/trinity_out_dir/Trinity.fasta"                                                                                                                                                         
threads: 15                                                                                                                                                                                         
shell:                                                                                                                                                                                              
    '''                                                                                                                                                                                             
    singularity exec -e {trinity_path} Trinity --seqType fq --max_memory 450G --left SRR12102895_1.fastq.gz --right SRR12102895_2.fastq.gz --CPU 15 --trimmomatic --quality_trimming_params "all.fa:2:30:10 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:5 LEADING:5 TRAILING:5 MINLEN:25" --output trinity_out_dir                                                                                                                                                                                         
    '''
```

when I run `python3 run_pipeline.py samples.txt`, I get the error:

```
name 'taxon' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum example:

For `sample.txt`, I would provide sample instead of reads.

```
Solatube DRR350770 all.fa Y
```

`run_pipeline.py`

```
import argparse
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run Snakemake pipeline with Trinity assemble or not")
parser.add_argument("samples", help="path to samples.txt")
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.samples) as f:
    for line in f:
        taxon, sample, adapters, assembly = [x.strip() for x in line.split()]
        if assembly == "Y":
            os.system(f"snakemake -s SNPwAssembly.smk --cores 16 --config taxon={taxon} sample={sample} adapters={adapters}")
```

For your `SNPwAssembly.smk` file:

```
TAXON = config['taxon']
SAMPLES = config['sample']
ADAPTERS = config['adapters']


print (TAXON)
print (SAMPLES)
print (ADAPTERS)

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{taxon}/{sample}_trinity/Trinity.fastq", taxon = TAXON, sample = SAMPLES)


rule test:
    input:
        read1 = "{taxon}/{sample}_1.fastq.gz",
        read2 = "{taxon}/{sample}_2.fastq.gz", 
    output:
        "{taxon}/{sample}_trinity/Trinity.fastq"
    params:
        adaptor = config['adapters']
    threads: 1
    shell:                                                                                                    
        """
        echo {input.read1} {input.read2} {params} {threads} > {output}
        """
```

Comment: This fixed taxon, but now I get the error "Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'READ1'"

Comment: Similar to taxon you need to provide the read information to snakemake. I have modified the answer for your additional question.